# Python: How to get a unit vector along a given numbered axis?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I start with a vector, say (a,b,c), and I want to get back a collection of three unit vectors in n dimensions, the first along axis a, the second along axis b and the third axis c. How can I do this without just looping over all my values.

Comment: use `axis` parameter of `np.sum()`?

Comment: What is `n` in your description? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.eye(3)` to make the 3x3 identity, then you can reference each column.

Comment: Those aren’t the requested **unit** vectors.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I've updated the answer to fix it.